# CSS body class jquery switcher with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am using a background switcher so far compiled from a few examples and tutorials I have found around, it consists of a stylesheet and a few child classes that each contain a different background image; when the switcher image is clicked, the javascript sequentially toggles the next body class in order and writes a new value to the cookie. Everything works okay except for the cookie loading upon page load. If I refresh the page, the cookie does not recall, and thus the body class does not default to the last selected class. Here is the code

Here is a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lse3V/2/

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="background switcha" /> 
        <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
        <title>background switcha</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="head.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">head.js( "jquery.js","back.js",  function() { });</script>
</head>
<body class="orig">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="backgroundswap"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body.green{background: #3F0 url(background1.jpg) center top fixed repeat}
body.blue{background: #00F url(background2.jpg) center -80px fixed repeat}
body.red{background: #F00 url(background3.jpg) center top fixed repeat}
body.grey,html{background: #666 url(background4.jpg) repeat}
body{min-height:800px}
#backgroundswap{display:block;display:inline-block;zoom:1;width:101px;height:22px;background-image:url(backgroundswap.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-bottom:12px;}
body.green #backgroundswap{background-position:center bottom}
body.blue #backgroundswap{background-position:0 -66px}
body.red #backgroundswap{background-position:0 -44px}
body.grey #backgroundswap{background-position:0 -22px}
body.orig{background-position:0 0}

body.orig{
background: #FF0 url(background5.jpg) center top fixed repeat
}
```

back.js

```
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
    if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
        options = options || {};
        if (value === null) {
            value = '';
            options.expires = -1;
        }
        var expires = '';
        if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
            var date;
            if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            } else {
                date = options.expires;
            }
            expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
        }

        var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
        var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
        var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
        document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
    } else { 
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Switch backgrounds and create the cookie...

    $("#backgroundswap").click(function(){

        var old_bg = ["green","blue","red","grey","orig"];

        var new_bg = ["blue","red","grey","orig","green"];

        var currentClass = $('body').attr("class");

            if(!Array.indexOf){ Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){ for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){ if(this[i]===obj){ return i; } } return -1; } }

        $('body').removeClass().addClass(new_bg[old_bg.indexOf(currentClass)]);

        $.cookie('backswap', old_bg.indexOf($('body').attr("class")), { path: '/', expires: 365 });


    });

  });
```

head.js

```
 (function(a){var b=a.documentElement,c=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")!=-1,d=false,e=[],f={},g={},h=a.createElement("script").async===true||"MozAppearance"in a.documentElement.style||window.opera;var i=window.head_conf&&head_conf.head||"head",j=window[i]=window[i]||function(){j.ready.apply(null,arguments)};var k=0,l=1,m=2,n=3;h?j.js=function(){var a=arguments,b=a[a.length-1],c=[];r(b)||(b=null),q(a,function(d,e){d!=b&&(d=p(d),c.push(d),v(d,b&&e==a.length-2?function(){s(c)&&b()}:null))});return j}:j.js=function(){var a=arguments,b=[].slice.call(a,1),c=b[0];if(!d){e.push(function(){j.js.apply(null,a)});return j}c?(q(b,function(a){r(a)||u(p(a))}),v(p(a[0]),r(c)?c:function(){j.js.apply(null,b)})):v(p(a[0]));return j},j.ready=function(a,b){r(a)&&(b=a,a="ALL");var c=g[a];if(c&&c.state==n||a=="ALL"&&s()){b();return j}var d=f[a];d?d.push(b):d=f[a]=[b];return j};function o(a){var b=a.split("/"),c=b[b.length-1],d=c.indexOf("?");return d!=-1?c.substring(0,d):c}function p(a){var b;if(typeof a=="object")for(var c in a)a[c]&&(b={name:c,url:a[c]});else b={name:o(a),url:a};var d=g[b.name];if(d)return d;for(var e in g)if(g[e].url==b.url)return g[e];g[b.name]=b;return b}function q(a,b){if(a){typeof a=="object"&&(a=[].slice.call(a));for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++)b.call(a,a[c],c)}}function r(a){return Object.prototype.toString.call(a)=="[object Function]"}function s(a){a=a||g;for(var b in a)if(a[b].state!=n)return false;return true}function t(a){a.state=k,q(a.onpreload,function(a){a.call()})}function u(a,b){a.state||(a.state=l,a.onpreload=[],w({src:a.url,type:"cache"},function(){t(a)}))}function v(a,b){if(a.state==n&&b)return b();if(a.state==m)return j.ready(a.name,b);if(a.state==l)return a.onpreload.push(function(){v(a,b)});a.state=m,w(a.url,function(){a.state=n,b&&b(),q(f[a.name],function(a){a()}),s()&&q(f.ALL,function(a){a.done||a(),a.done=true})})}function w(c,d){var e=a.createElement("script");e.type="text/"+(c.type||"javascript"),e.src=c.src||c,e.async=false,e.onreadystatechange=e.onload=function(){var a=e.readyState;!d.done&&(!a||/loaded|complete/.test(a))&&(d(),d.done=true)},b.appendChild(e)}setTimeout(function(){d=true,q(e,function(a){a()})},300),!a.readyState&&a.addEventListener&&(a.readyState="loading",a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler=function(){a.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler,false),a.readyState="complete"},false))})(document)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the cookie great, but there's nothing to check whether it's set or act on it if it does detect it. This bit of code will do just that for ya.

```
if($.cookie('backswap')) {

    $('body').removeClass().addClass(old_bg[$.cookie('backswap')]);

};
```

There's some other minor adjustments to ensure the arrays are scoped for everything, so here's the entire chunk of code that's affected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.new_bg = ["blue","red","grey","orig","green"]; 
    window.old_bg = ["green","blue","red","grey","orig"];

    if($.cookie('backswap')) {

        $('body').removeClass().addClass(old_bg[$.cookie('backswap')]);

    };


    //Switch backgrounds and create the cookie...

    $("#backgroundswap").click(function(){

        currentClass = $('body').attr("class");

        $('body').removeClass().addClass(new_bg[old_bg.indexOf(currentClass)]);

        $.cookie('backswap', old_bg.indexOf($('body').attr("class")), { path: '/', expires: 365 });

    });

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is ABSOLUTELY PERFECT!! I can't thank you enough, I struggled with that for a week and couldn't stop thinking about how to fix it, really, really appreciate it, Blake!!